# Monero cpu mining handling huge number of machines

Tags: mining-pools, cpu-mining

I am going to cpu farm Monero with hundreds of computers. And they are the computers of our workers in our company. I want to see whenever their machine is on and working for me. Which pool provides this? I want to see a list of machines that are online at the moment and their hashrate exc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could setup your own mining pool using [node-cryptonote-pool](https://github.com/zone117x/node-cryptonote-pool) or something similar. Then each computer could mine for the pool